# Swift 5 Parsing strange json format

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swift5, jsondecoder

I'm trying to parse JSON but keep getting incorrect format error. The JSON I get back from FoodData Central (the USDA's Nutrition API) is as follows:

```
{
    dataType = "Survey (FNDDS)";
    description = "Chicken thigh, NS as to cooking method, skin not eaten";
    fdcId = 782172;
    foodNutrients =     (
                {
            amount = "24.09";
            id = 9141826;
            nutrient =             {
                id = 1003;
                name = Protein;
                number = 203;
                rank = 600;
                unitName = g;
            };
            type = FoodNutrient;
        },
                {
            amount = "10.74";
            id = "9141827";
            nutrient =             {
                id = 1004;
                name = "Total lipid (fat)";
                number = 204;
                rank = 800;
                unitName = g;
            };
            type = FoodNutrient;
        }
    );
}
```

My Structs:

```
struct Root: Decodable {
     let description: String
     let foodNutrients: FoodNutrients
}

struct FoodNutrients: Decodable {
     // What should go here???
}
```

From the JSON, it looks like foodNutrients is an array of unnamed objects, each of which has the values amount: String, id: String, and nutrient: Nutrient (which has id, name etc...) However, forgetting the Nutrient object, I can't even parse the amounts.

```
struct FoodNutrients: Decodable {
     let amounts: [String]
}
```

I don't think its an array of string, but I have no idea what the () in foodNutrients would indicate.

How would I go about parsing this JSON. I'm using Swift 5 and JSONDecoder. To get the JSON I use JSONSerializer, then print out the JSON above.

Comment: Its not a well formatted json. I checked at a json formatter and validator. INVALID (RFC 8259)

Comment: I checked that as well, which is strange because it is coming from the USDA's API. All I'm doing to get that response is using JSONSerialization to convert the data to JSON, then printing it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The () in foodNutrients indicates that it holds an array of objects - in that case FoodNutrient objects. Therefore your root object should look like this:

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let description: String
    let foodNutrients: [FoodNutrient]
}
```

Now the foodNutrient is except for the nutrient object straightforward:

```
struct FoodNutrient: Decodable {
    let id: Int // <-- in your example it is an integer and in the second object a string, choose the fitting one from the API
    let amount: String
    let nutrient: Nutrient
}
```

And the nutrient object should look like this:

```
struct Nutrient: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let number: Int
    let rank: Int
    let unitName: String 
}
```

Using `Decodable` is a good and easy way to serialize JSON. Hope that helps. Happy coding :)

Comment: I get the same error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: This solution is correct. The only problem is the amount variable is registering as a Double rather than a String

Answer (score 3):

This is **not** a JSON. This is a property list in the [`openStep`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/propertylistserialization/propertylistformat/openstep) format.

This is how it can be modelled (use `String` instead of `Int`):

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let description: String
    let foodNutrients: [FoodNutrient]
}

struct FoodNutrient: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let amount: String
    let nutrient: Nutrient
}

struct Nutrient: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let number: String
    let rank: String
    let unitName: String
}
```

And then decode it like this:

```
try PropertyListDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: yourStr)
```

Comment: I get this error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: @Nobadi Are you trying to decode the exact data you posted? And do not print `error.localizedDescription` - it's meaningless. Cast the error as `DecodingError` instead.

Comment: negative. I am only showing piece as the entire response from RESTApi is enormous. However, I pasted the entire response in a google docs: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1agT5EfVLqKuv43gxSXTgbzdmcDNfYHkhVear8M1Gfjw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: and what would I do after casting it to a DecodingError?

Comment: @Nobadi Print it. Debug. Check which type of DecodingError it is. I've shown you how to decode the example from your question. You should now be able to do the rest.

Comment: thanks so much, I did end up figuring it out after printing the error rather than localized description. After debugging, I found the JSON is actually fine, but the amount variable is not a String, it's a Double (which is strange because it is wrapped in "", but oh well) I appreciate the prompt and direct responses